# Reading with Hibernate Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Hibernate Criteria API in my project.
In this API, `list()` method is used to get a number of records from db.
My question is : How to get only one record from db (without using `list()` method as there is no need)?

Comment: the hibernate docs are poorly laid out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're certain that the query is going to return at most one record, use [`Criteria#uniqueResult()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#uniqueResult()).

If the query can return more than one record, but you're fine with just getting the first result, you could combine `uniqueResult()` with [`Criteria#setMaxResults()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setMaxResults(int)).